# Can someone explain this code?

Tags: scala

Novice here. I came across this following piece of code

```
class A
class B extends A
val printB: B => Unit = { b => println("Blah blah") }
```

Can someone explain the `printB` function? I cannot understand what is `b`, since it isn't defined anywhere.

Comment: http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/anonymous-function-syntax.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`printB` is an anonymous function. It acts like this method:

```
 def printBmethod(b: B): Unit = { println("Blah blah") }
```

Except that to make it a function, you have to [eta-expand](https://gleichmann.wordpress.com/2011/01/09/functional-scala-turning-methods-into-functions/) it like:

```
 val printB = printBmethod _
```

See also: [Difference between method and function in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529184/difference-between-method-and-function-in-scala)

Explaining the lambda itself, `b` is an input parameter, so you can call it like:

```
 printB(new B)
```

`B => Unit` means a function which takes `B` and returns `Unit` so scala is looking for something that takes `B` and returns `Unit` - like `b: B => ...`

P.S. The raw code without type inference for `b` looks like:

```
val printB: B => Unit = { b: B => println("Blah blah") }
```

So here you see what actually `b` is.